# Solving a linear system with Cholesky factorization

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, matrix-decomposition

So, I've reached the following problem:
Given $A \in R^{nxn} $  positive-definite and symmetrical, $B\in R^{nxn}$ and the vector $c\in R^n$ write an algorithm to solve to following situation:

$Ax=Bc$

After I break down A with Cholesky in $ L * L^t $ I don't know how should I proceed, should I get the inverse and find x or is there a easier method?

Comment: It's easy to find the inverse of $L$ because it's already lower-triangular

Comment: It is in the same spirit as using the LU factorization for solving a system.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The idea is the same of [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Solving_linear_equations), i.e. use the triangular for of the matrix $L$.

For simplicity put, $Bc = b \, \in \mathbb{R}^n$, so the system is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Ax &= b \\
L L^{T} x &= b
\end{aligned}
$$
now you call $L^{T} x = y $ and you solve the system:
$$
\left \{
    \begin{aligned}
     Ly &= b \\
     L^{T} x &= y
    \end{aligned}
\right.
$$

The matrix $L$ is triangular so you solve it directly with [forward and back substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_and_back_substitution), first $Ly =b$ and after $L^{T} x = y$.

See also [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Applications).