# Solution to Triangular Systems with Cholesky Factor

Tags: linear-algebra, cholesky-decomposition

The answer in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422012/solving-a-linear-system-with-cholesky-factorization) describes the solution to this linear system

$$
\begin{aligned}
Ax &= b \\
L L^{T} x &= b
\end{aligned}
$$

as solving the two triangular systems.

$$
\left \{
    \begin{aligned}
     Ly &= b \\
     L^{T} x &= y
    \end{aligned}
\right.
$$

I use this solution often and was recently asked, "what is $y$?" I commonly brush this off as being just a vector serving the provisional values for step 1, but are not of substantive interest. What we really want is the solution to $x$.

My statement is true-ish, but lacks a mathematically rigorous answer for "what is $y$?"

What might be a more sophisticated and rigorous answer for explaining what $y$ is in this solution?

Comment: Isn't it $y=L^tx$? In the original system, the second equation (with parentheses) is $L(L^tx)=b$. So, you are manufacturing another equation by the substitution: $L^tx=y$

Comment: Thanks, @SlipEternal. But, the original post I cite has the right algebraic representation for these triangular systems. We first forward solve for y and then backsolve for x. My definition of y however lacks good rigor.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. What do you mean it lacks mathematical rigor? It is not "just a vector". That makes it sound so arbitrary. It is a particular transformation. $$LL^tx$$ can be thought of as the transformation of $x$ by the transform $A=LL^t$, or it could be thought of as the transform $L$ of the vector $L^tx$. This latter interpretation gives rise to $L^tx = y$ as the vector to be transformed by $L$ in order to get $b$.

Comment: @SlipEternal IMHO, the question is not there. The OP could have asked : "is there a kind of intuitive (physical ?) interpretation of vector $y$ ?". A comparison comes to my mind: the jacobian that can be described "technicaly" as the determinant of the partial derivatives, but is better understood intuitively as a ratio of infinitesimal areas.